# No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, pygame, python-module

I'm workin on macOS 10.15.6. I need the Pygame module and I can't seem to import it in a project.

```
MacBook-Pro:program my_username$ python3 program.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

If I try to use `import pygame as pygame`, I get this:

```
MacBook-Pro:program my_username$ python3 program.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame as pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

When I type `pip3 install pygame`, I get `Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1)`.

I tried to add `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1)` to the path using [this tutorial](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/).

`echo $PATH` gives me:

```
/usr/local/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/lib/python3.9:
```

IDLE 3 finds pygame:

```
>>> import pygame
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Can you help me? What should I do to use pygame?

Comment: Maybe you can try `!pip install pygame`

Comment: What's the signification of the ``pip!``? It doesn't work either

Comment: what's the error message?, maybe in a more conventional way `import pygame as pygame`

Comment: I forgot to write it. I get ``ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'``.

Comment: Maybe you can try this command into shell `python -m pip install pygame`, and then try again `import pygame as pygame` in your python IDE

Comment: What's the signification of ``!pip`` and ``-m pip``?

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez that form isn't 'more conventional' it is redundant. - the 'as' is to give the module an alias, so all that import is doing is giving pygame an alias of pygame. Literally the 'as' clause simply changes the name that is available in the local namespac - it wont find the module if the module doesn't exist.

Comment: I didn't ask the signification of ``pip`` (I used it as written in the question) but the signification of ``!pip``.

Answer (score 1):

To start, it's highly advised that you check for python virtual environment usage, your project might using venv and the interpreter associated with your project isn't pointing it's `PYTHONPATH` to the mentioned address.
You can try 2 things:

1. Use this code at the beginning of your code (Some kind of temporary solution)

> ```
> import sys
> sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1)")
> ```

2. Run your python code (assuming you're not using any kind of IDE):

> PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1):$PYTHONPATH python3 your-code

Comment: What do you mean by "check for python environment usage"? Where should I write ``PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1):$PYTHONPATH python3 ``?

Comment: Open your terminal, type "touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile" in textedit, add "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages". Save the file using command + Q, then run "source ~/.bash_profile" in terminal. If my instructions are unclear, this is an [article](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html) on it all.

Comment: Adding ``-m`` during the installation of the module worked but this solution seems to give better result if someone forgets to add ``-m`` or if adding that doesn't work. However, it raises other errors of non existing modules.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the above answer, you may be using a virtual environment. Are you using Pycharm? If so, either create a new project and check ***use default system interpreter*** or something on the lines of that.

You could also add modules to the virtual environment by going to `File>Preferences (or settings)>Project:(project name)>Python Interpreter`, press the `+` button and search for `pygame`.